# How to remove handler and hibernateinitializer in rest xml

Tags: spring-rest

I got this xml  format rest in Spring Boot Rest and like to know how to remove  `<handler>` and  `<hibernateLazyInitializer/>`.

```
<Student_.._jvst83b_0>
<id>1</id>
<name>Thaw Thaw</name>
<age>23</age>
<school>Latha</school>
<handler/>
<hibernateLazyInitializer/>
</Student_.._jvst83b_0>
```

my rest controller code is

```
@GetMapping(value = "/student/{id}",produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE
        ,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public Student findStudentById(@PathVariable("id") int id){
    return studentService.findById(id);
}
```

Comment: xml is for what purpose?

Comment: i like to demostrate Content Negiotiation in both XML and Json.